# Export Sql data to .csv and generate separate .csv files per table based on query

Tags: mysql, go, export-to-csv

Currently, I am using Go to access my database. Ideally, I'd like to generate  .csv based on the table's name and export data to those files based on the query.

For example, if I ran:

```
select t1.*,t2.* from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t2.table_1_id = t1.id
where t1.linking_id = 22
```

I'd like a .csv file generated for both table 1 and table 2 where data from each table would generate and then export into these two generated files with the same names as the table's names.

I know in PHP I can use `$fp = fopen(getcwd().'/table1.csv', 'w');
                fputcsv($fp, $columns);`
to generate the .csv files with the table's row names. But, I don't believe go needs continuous duplication of foreah columns to generate separate .csv files.

I would like some guidance on exporting and generating sql data to .csv files.

Thank you!

My current import set-up is:

`import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" 
    "github.com/joho/sqltocsv"
)`

Im able to connect to my database without issue, and query my database when initializing the query via `rows, _:= db.Query(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 22)`

I am able to write the query data to a pre-existing .csv file using `err = sqltocsv.WriteFile("results.csv", rows)`

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm uncertain how to export data from my database using GoLang, and then create .csv files  based on the specific table data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate the `rows` with a loop to fetch each row
2. Use package [`encoding/csv`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) to write a CSV file.